# An exercise with linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm solving the following exercise: $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$

> Let $f: \RR^3 \rightarrow \RR^4: (a,b,c) \mapsto (a+2b+c, b+c, a + 2b + 3c, a + b + 2c)$
>
> 1. Find the basis of $f^{-1}(E)$ where $E = \langle (1,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1) \rangle$
> 2. Do there exist some bases $A$ and $B$ of the spaces $\RR^3$ and $\RR^4$ respectively, that
>      $$M^B_A(f) = \left[
>    \begin{matrix}
>    1 & -1 & 0 \\
>    0 & 1 & -1 \\
>    1 & 0 & -1 \\
>    1 & -2 & 1
>    \end{matrix}
>     \right]$$
>      If yes, find these bases. $M^B_A(f)$ signifies the transformation matrix in bases $A, B$

First of all, point 1. is easy in this case, since by solving a simple equation system, one can prove that $f$ is injecitve. Hence, in 1. is suffices to find the preimage of the two base vectors. This preimage is the desired base.

But this reasoning would fail if $f$ were **not** a monomorphism. We can easily show that in the standard basis $$D = M(f) =  \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{matrix}
 \right]$$
so let's assume that $g(v) = D^T v$. Then it's a mapping $\RR^4 \rightarrow \RR^3$ which cannot be injective. How could we solve the problem in this case? Some hint please ;)

In 2. I can't boil it down to a simple equation system to determine the bases (and it's what most computational linear algebra exercises are all about)

Can you give me a hint here too?

Comment: Part 1 might be difficult since $(1,1,0,0)$ isn’t in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, for 1° solve the systems $f(a,b,c)=(1,1,0,0)$ and $f(a,b,c,)=(0,0,1,1)$ "in a,b,c".$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$

For 2° and if {$v_1,v_2,v_3$} is a basic of $\RR^3$, do the same work, it means solve the systems $f(v_1)=(1,0,1,1)$, $f(v_2)=(-1,1,0,-2)$ and $f(v_3)=(0,-1,-1,1)$

Comment: I'm asking about a mapping $\RR^4 \rightarrow \RR^3$. ($g(v) = D^T v$)  The method for 1) you presented is exactly what I proposed and makes use of the injectiveness.

Comment: And 2) asks: what should $v_i$ be so that $f(v_i)$ has coordinates $(1,0,1,1)$ in the **standard base**. And if the equation system would be inconsistent here, it doesn't answer the question: *does there exist any non-standard base for $\RR^4$ that $f(v_i)$ has these coordinates?*